# JS Retry function several times to see if it returns true

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a better way to retry if a function returns true or false

```
   function foo() { // 
        var tabList = window.content.document.getElementById('compTabs') // this might be null if page is not loaded and further code wont work
        if (!tabList) { // stop here if tab list is null
            return false;
        }
    // continue and finish function
        }


// this is a loop that will go trough an array and this check needs to happen for each element of the array 
for (var i; i < loopLenght; i++) {
    // This is the actual code nothing else happens here.
        if ( !foo() ) {
            // try again
            if ( !foo() ) {
                // try one more time
                if ( !foo() ) {
                    console.log('Failed')
                }
            }
        }
   // a lot more code coming here that should only run one per iteration
}
```

I'm just looking for a nicer, cleaner way to write the code above.

Comment: You should add the complete code, not just pseudo-code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: How about `while(true)` ?

Comment: Using a loop would be neater, and make it easy to later change the number of retries. Or if you don't want you do anything specific in between retries you can use a single if statement (taking advantage of short-circuit evaluation): `if(!foo() && !foo() && !foo()) { /* failed */} else { /* succeeded */} `

Comment: @RayonDabre If he does it like this, he can end up with infinite loop. Maybe `var i = 0; while(foo() || i <3){... i++;}` so he controls how many times checks are repeated...

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic, Yes...Makes more sense...

Comment: Is the foo() a synchronous function, i mean, does it emmediately return true/false? When asnychronity is involved the retry must be handled in some callback scheme..

Comment: Use recursion. Especially when your function is asynchronous.

Comment: Added more code so you have a better understanding of what I'm trying. @fast the code immediately returns false.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var retries = 5;
var success = false;

while (retries-- > 0 && !(success = foo())) {}

console.log(success);
```

Here, `retries--` counts down with every loop iteration and `success = foo()` executes `foo()` and saves the result into `success`.

If either `retries` hits `0` or `success` becomes `true`, the loop stops. A loop body is not needed.

Warning: **This will not work if `foo()` is an asynchronous function.**

Comment: This is close but I need to stop further code from happening if after 5 retries it's still fails, which means adding another if condition on success, was trying to shorten the code as much as possible.

Comment: And...? You have the value of `retries` and the value of `success` after the loop, I'm pretty sure you can figure something out. (I'm not sure why "adding another `if` condition" would be undesirable.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you in a browser?  (As opposed to Node etc.)
Does it have to retry specifically N times?

```
while (!condition) { }
```

But that'll block and hang your thread.

If you want to poll ...

```
function whileConditionNotMet()
{
   if (!condition) {
       setTimeout(whileConditionNotSet, 1000);
       return false;
   }

   // Condition met
   // ...
   return true;
}
```

You could limit the number of times it checks by incrementing a static variable:

```
function whileConditionNotMet()
{
   if ( typeof whileConditionNotMet.counter == 'undefined' ) {
       whileConditionNotMet.counter = 0;
   }

   if (whileConditionNotMet.counter++ > 10) {
       // Timeout
       // ...
       return false;
   }

   if (!condition) {
       setTimeout(whileConditionNotSet, 1000);
       return false;
   }

   // Condition met
   // ...
   return true;
}
```

...or...

```
var counter = 0;
while (!condition && counter++ < 10) { }
```

Comment: No node, a javascript  + jquery script ran in FireFox.

Comment: Depending on what you need to have happen - (i.e. if it doesn't matter if there's a polling-delay, vs you need as-fast-as-possible responsiveness for the UI) - you might consider looking at having some background task chewing away at the polling (see below).  Otherwise I'd just cheat and use setTimeout() to handle periodic "wake up and check the state" - so you don't block user interaction too heavily.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 3):

```
async function Retry( action, retryInterval = 5000, maxAttemptCount = 3 )
{
    const exceptions = [];
    for ( let attempted = 0 ; attempted < maxAttemptCount ; attempted++ )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( attempted > 0 )
                await sleep( retryInterval );
            return action( );
        }
        catch ( e )
        {
            exceptions.push( e );
        }
    }

    return exceptions;
}

function sleep( ms ) { return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, ms ) ); }
```

To use:

```
Retry( function( ) { return 534 * 9 } ).then( (result) => { console.log( result ); } );

//retry 3 times with 5s interval
Retry( function( ) { throw "Exception" } ).then( (result) => { console.log( result ); } );

//retry 5 times with a 2s interval
Retry( function( ) { throw "Exception" }, 2000, 5 ).then( (result) => { console.log( result ); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

See what I wrote:

```
// -------------- RETRIES CLASS 151118 -------------------
// executeFunction     - Returns true if success, false otherwise
// limitRetries        - max number of retries
// sleepInBetweenMilli - the delay in millis between one retry to another
    function Retrier(executeFunction, limitRetries, sleepInBetweenMilli, successCallback, failCallback) {
        this.executeFunction = executeFunction;
        this.limitRetries = limitRetries;
        this.sleepInBetweenMilli = sleepInBetweenMilli;
        this.successCallback = successCallback;
        this.failCallback = failCallback;
        this.thisRetry = 1;

        var RetrierObjectThis = this;

        function doCycle() {
            var result = RetrierObjectThis.executeFunction();
            if (result == true) {
                RetrierObjectThis.successCallback();
            } else {
                if (RetrierObjectThis.thisRetry >= RetrierObjectThis.limitRetries) {
                    RetrierObjectThis.failCallback();
                } else {
                    RetrierObjectThis.thisRetry++;
                    setTimeout(doCycle, RetrierObjectThis.sleepInBetweenMilli);
                }
            }
        } 

        doCycle();

    }
```