YouTube Caption Scraper Randomly Fails with "Could not find captions for video"
I'm trying to grab YouTube video captions using the youtube-captions-scraper package. Most of the time, it works perfectly, but sometimes it fails with the following error: Could not find captions for video: video-id
This error seems to occur randomly, even for videos where captions are available when checked manually.
const { getSubtitles } = require('youtube-captions-scraper');

const videoId = 'some-video-id';

getSubtitles({
  videoID: videoId, // YouTube video ID
  lang: 'en' // language code
})
.then(captions => {
  console.log(captions);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Error:', err.message);
});


The video definitely has captions (I verified them on the YouTube).
The error does not always occur for the same video ID; sometimes the same video will work fine on subsequent attempts.
I have tried this on different networks and systems, but the behavior is inconsistent.

Has anyone faced this issue or know why this happens? Could it be related to rate-limiting or API throttling by YouTube? Any advice on how to handle this more gracefully or avoid the error altogether would be appreciated.

Share the video_ids you used for test this code. Also, consider post the issue on their Github page

I believe YouTube has a proper, well documented API for retrieving captions.

Assuming you don't have any performance concerns, you can just retry when it happens (see example of retry mechanism here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329792/js-retry-function-several-times-to-see-if-it-returns-true).

This library contains one small function. You can see the code here.
The part that yields that error is this:
  const data = await fetchData(
    `https://youtube.com/watch?v=${videoID}`
  );

  // * ensure we have access to captions data
  if (!data.includes('captionTracks'))
    throw new Error(`Could not find captions for video: ${videoID}`);

This means the response is good, but the content is not what expected. It's probably a defense against scrapers like a captcha test. You may have better results if you use a headless browser like puppeteer to fetch the HTML. Also consider using different proxies for even better success rate.
Once you get html using puppeteer, or using fetch with rotating proxies, you can then use following module which is a based on the source code of the library with an additional param: the HTML of the video's page.
import he from 'he';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  find
} from 'lodash';
import striptags from 'striptags';

const fetchData =
  typeof fetch === 'function' ?
  async function fetchData(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.text();
  } :
  async function fetchData(url) {
    const {
      data
    } = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  };

export async function getSubtitles({
  videoID,
  lang = 'en',
}: {
  videoID: string,
  lang: 'en' | 'de' | 'fr' | void,
}, html) {
  const data = html || await fetchData(
    `https://youtube.com/watch?v=${videoID}`
  );

  // * ensure we have access to captions data
  if (!data.includes('captionTracks'))
    throw new Error(`Could not find captions for video: ${videoID}`);

  const regex = /"captionTracks":(\[.*?\])/;
  const [match] = regex.exec(data);

  const {
    captionTracks
  } = JSON.parse(`{${match}}`);
  const subtitle =
    find(captionTracks, {
      vssId: `.${lang}`,
    }) ||
    find(captionTracks, {
      vssId: `a.${lang}`,
    }) ||
    find(captionTracks, ({
      vssId
    }) => vssId && vssId.match(`.${lang}`));

  // * ensure we have found the correct subtitle lang
  if (!subtitle || (subtitle && !subtitle.baseUrl))
    throw new Error(`Could not find ${lang} captions for ${videoID}`);

  const transcript = await fetchData(subtitle.baseUrl);
  const lines = transcript
    .replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><transcript>', '')
    .replace('</transcript>', '')
    .split('</text>')
    .filter(line => line && line.trim())
    .map(line => {
      const startRegex = /start="([\d.]+)"/;
      const durRegex = /dur="([\d.]+)"/;

      const [, start] = startRegex.exec(line);
      const [, dur] = durRegex.exec(line);

      const htmlText = line
        .replace(/<text.+>/, '')
        .replace(/&amp;/gi, '&')
        .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');

      const decodedText = he.decode(htmlText);
      const text = striptags(decodedText);

      return {
        start,
        dur,
        text,
      };
    });

  return lines;
}


We were using puppeteer earlier but if we create an API with puppeteer, then the response time is too high. Do you have any suggestions to optimize the same. We are currently using lambda to run the scraper.

you can fall back to puppeteer if regular fetch fails. or you can use proxies with regular fetch. you can find provider who offers 10 free proxies, or 100 for less than 5$ a month.
